# How to uncheck url path settings in node form alter for existing content?

Tags: path-aliases, nodes

Here I wonder how to uncheck url path settings in node form alter for existing content?

Comment: yes, but in node form with existing content

Comment: you want " Generate automatic URL alias " to be unchecked in the node in URL Settings?

Comment: yes, in node edit form only

Comment: @bisw Try `hook_form_alter` and perform check off operation based on your requirement.

Comment: yes i have already tried this but it does not contain any variable or form element related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer two ways of doing it

**Method 1:**

```
function module_node_update($node) {
  if($node->type == "blog"){
        $node->path['pathauto'] = TRUE;//to be checked
        $node->path['pathauto'] = FALSE;//To be unchecked
  }
}
```

or either you can do it in **node_presave**

**Method 2:**

```
function module_node_presave($node){
 if($node->type == "blog"){
            $node->path['pathauto'] = TRUE;//to be checked
            $node->path['pathauto'] = FALSE;//To be unchecked
      }
}
```

Try and let me know hope it helps 
:)

Comment: I have already mention  'uncheck url path settings in node form alter for existing contentt'.

Comment: What you can do is load all nid needed to be updated load it using node load and set "$node->path['pathauto'] = FALSE;" and save it using node_save if that even not working try reading https://www.drupal.org/node/1973628 and https://www.drupal.org/node/1422908 some extend to get near answer.

Comment: i believe you cant do it with form_alter it will be nightmare. even if you do it with form alter you can only do it for only one node at a time not all the nodes at a same time. This is what i know from my knowledge.